# Optional Model Properties Binding in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created one `AccountModel` which has following properties

```
public class AccountModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
    [Compare("Password")]
    [BindRequired]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use same model for `SignUp` and `SignIn`. This model is perfectly working for signup but when I am using same model for `SignIn` my model becomes Invalid.

I know the reason because, I am not passing value for Confirm Password property. I tried following

1. I made `NULLABLE` by using "?" bu it is giving me warning (See attached screenshot) 
   [image]
2. I have also tried `[BindRequired]` annotation which is also not working.

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and trying to use single Model for both login and signup.

Is there any solution for that? I am learning .NET Core & MVC so having less knowledge about this subject.

Help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **Nullable contexts**, based on its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts):

> Nullable contexts enable fine-grained control for how the compiler interprets reference type variables. The nullable annotation context of any given source line is either enabled or disabled. You can think of the pre-C# 8.0 compiler as compiling all your code in a disabled nullable context: any reference type may be null. The nullable warnings context may also be enabled or disabled. The nullable warnings context specifies the warnings generated by the compiler using its flow analysis.

You can get rid of this warning like this:

```cs
#nullable enable
    public string? ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
#nullable disable
```

As another workaround, if you want to always get rid of this warning in your project, you can add the `Nullable` element in your `.csproj` file. Right click on your project and click "Edit Project File", then add the `Nullable` element to your `PropertyGroup` section, just like the following:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You just need to *Re-Build* your project once to see the result.