# Nullability warning for Task.FromResult

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0, c#-8.0, nullability

We have the following method in our code base (.NET Standard 2.0 library):

```
public Task<T> GetDefaultTask<T>()
{
    return Task.FromResult(default(T));
}
```

We're currently trying to shift to C# 8.0 Nullability and get a warning in the code above:

> warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'result' in 'Task Task.FromResult(T result)'.

Why do we get this warning? To me, it looks perfectly fine, to pass `null` as the parameter to `Task.FromResult`.

**Important note:** We want to allow the Task to contain a null value. But adding `Task<T?>` would force us to add type constraints which we cannot do.

Comment: aren't you declaring an expectation of a non nullable T  (Task<T>) and yet have default(T) returning, which is null for reference types? One way would be to change to T? but then you would need to restrict to class. Or us default! instead of default to deny nullability.

Comment: Regardless of whether this could be a good or bad idea, you can get rid of this warning by Enable/Disable commands, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61436270/2946329

Comment: @Dmitri: I added an important note to elaborate the situation.

Answer (score 2):

If `T` is a non-nullable reference type, `null` shouldn't be passed to `Task.FromResult<T>`. The implementation of `Task.FromResult` doesn't care about null references and you could use `Task.FromResult(default(T)!)`, but then the caller of `GetDefaultTask` may receive a `Task<string>` when it should actually be a `Task<string?>`. Code like `GetDefaultTask<string>().Result.Length` would compile without warning and cause null reference exceptions at runtime.

As far as I know it's not currently possible to annotate the return type correctly in this situation.

Declaring the method as `Task<T?> GetDefaultTask<T>()` is not allowed since `T` could be either a struct or a reference type, and nullable structs and reference types are represented differently.

It is possible to solve this cleanly if `T` is constrained to be a reference type:

```
public Task<T?> GetDefaultTask<T>() where T : class
```

But adding that constraint may cause issues further up the call chain, depending on where that `T` parameter is coming from.

For similar situations where a generic return value could be either a struct or reference (such as `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`) there's the `[MaybeNull]`  attribute, but that can only be applied to the return value itself (the task in this case), not to the generic parameter of the task.

Comment: I've adjusted my question with an important note. Bottomline: there is no good way to do that?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. There is currently no way to declare that an unconstrained generic parameter may be either a nullable reference or a struct. This github issue links to some related discussions and possible future language changes: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29146

Answer (score -1):

> To me, it looks perfectly fine, to pass null as the parameter to `Task.FromResult`.

No, that is a bad idea.

If the caller specifies a non-nullable type for `T` then `default(T)` can be considered "undefined" (it's actually `null`, but that's a major shortcoming of C# 8.0's implementation of non-nullable-reference-types (i.e. they *can* still be `null`, grrrr). Consider:

```
// Compiled with C# 8.0's non-nullable reference-types enabled.

Task<String> task = GetDefaultTask<String>();
String result = await task;
Console.WriteLine( result.Length ); // <-- NullReferenceException at runtime even though the C# compiler reported `result` cannot be null.
```

Avoid using `default`/`default(T)` in C# 8.0 for generic types without adequate type-constraints.

There are a few solutions to this problem:

#### 1: Specify a caller-provided default-value:

```
public Task<T> GetDefaultTask<T>( T defaultValue )
{
    return Task.FromResult( defaultValue );
}
```

So the call-site needs to be updated and the C# compiler will give a warning or error if the caller tries to use `null` instead of an exception at runtime:

```
Task<String> task = GetDefaultTask<String>( defaultValue: null ); // <-- compiler error or warning because `null` cannot be used here.
String result = await task;
Console.WriteLine( result.Length );
```

#### 2: Add struct vs. class constraints on different methods:

The `default(T)` of a `struct`/value-type can be meaningful (or it could be just as dangerous as a `null`...), as we can safely use `default(T)` where `T : struct` but not `default(T)` where `T : class`, we can add different overloads for that case:

```
public Task<T> GetDefaultTask<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    return Task.FromResult( default(T) );
}

public Task<T> GetDefaultTask<T>( T defaultValue )
    where T : class
{
    return Task.FromResult( defaultValue );
}
```

(Note that you can't overload methods based purely on generic type constraints - you can only overload by generic parameter-count and ordinarily parameter types.

Comment: I've adjusted my question with an important additional note. If I read your post correctly there is no clean way to do that in C#8 as of now?

Comment: @D.R. Why can't you add type-constraints?